# How do we know the Temple Mount is the location of Solomen's Temple

Tags: beis-hamikdash

There is some archeologist that claim that the western wall is not part of The Holy Temple and that its actually a fortress wall of the romans,instead they claim the location 
of Beit HaMikdash is in the old city of David.

Comment: Can you link to any information about these alleged archeologists? I don't think they exist

Comment: Noone claims that the *Western Wall is anything other than part of the retaining wall built by Herod as part of his rebuilding effort.

Comment: There is a guy named Robert Cornuke who wrote a book about his theory of the Temple being south of the Mount. He describes himself as a Biblical archaeologist, but has no formal training(surprise!)
 and is the President of the "Bible Archaeology Search and Exploration Institute". Some of his points are listed on a Xtian site page: http://waytojesus.org/site-solomons-temple-south-temple-mount/   . There may be a renegade archaeologist or two with the same theory, but it's pretty much impossible, since real archaeologists have uncovered the wide staircases of ascent going UP to the Mount.

Comment: As far as what IS there, Dr Mazar's current excavations south of the Mount have uncovered a large royal/administrative complex, parts of it dating back to the United Monarchy.  She;s been working there for years, and thanks to pottery and other clues, is able to pinpoint the dating of stuff there to within 50 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

The Western Wall was constructed by Herod in order to serve as a retaining wall for the actual Temple Mount. It was not part of the Temple or temple mount, but was the closest Jews were allowed to approach by the gentile rulers.

[Western Wall](http://mosaic.lk.net/g-wall.html)

> The Western Wall in the midst of the Old City in Jerusalem is the
>   section of the Western supporting wall of the Temple Mount which has
>   remained intact since the destruction of the Second Jerusalem Temple
>   (70 C.E.). It became the most sacred spot in Jewish religious and
>   national consciousness and tradition by virtue of its proximity to the
>   Western Wall of the Holy of Holies in the Temple, from which,
>   according to numerous sources, the Divine Presence never departed. It
>   became a center of mourning over the destruction of the Temple and
>   Israel's exile, on the one hand, and of religious - in 20th century
>   also national - communion with the memory of Israel's former glory and
>   the hope for its restoration, on the other. Because of the former
>   association, it became known in European languages as the "Wailing
>   Wall".

The claim that you refer to was not made by archeologists, but by Arab fanatics attempting to deny any connection of the Jews to the land of Israel (even when ithat claim contradicts their own books).

['Western Wall was never part of temple'](http://www.jpost.com/Israel/Western-Wall-was-never-part-of-temple)  By MIKE SEID October 25, 2007

> The former mufti of Jerusalem, Ikrema Sabri, has made the claim that
>   there never was a Jewish temple on the Temple Mount, and the Western
>   Wall was really part of a mosque.

Of course he lied

> Archeologists overseeing Islamic infrastructure work on the Mount
>   announced this week that they had unveiled a sealed archeological
>   level dating back to the First Temple period. The First Temple was
>   built by King Solomon in the 10th century BCE, and destroyed by the
>   Babylonians in 586 BCE. The Second Temple was built 70 years later,
>   enlarged during the first century BCE by Herod, and destroyed by the
>   Romans in the year 70. The Dome of the Rock and Al-Aksa Mosque were
>   constructed on the Temple Mount site in the late seventh century.

[Archaeologists spotlight first Solomon’s Temple-era artifacts ever found on Temple Mount](http://www.timesofisrael.com/archaeologists-reveal-first-solomons-temple-era-artifacts-ever-found-on-temple-mount/).

> Israeli archaeologists on Thursday presented new details of what they
>   said were the first tiny artifacts, unearthed in situ on the Temple
>   Mount, ever conclusively dated to the time of the First Temple over
>   2,600 years ago. The discoveries were made during limited scientific
>   excavations carried out atop the flashpoint Temple Mount in the past
>   decade, the first of their kind since the British Mandate.

Many first and second temple era relics have been found in spill that the Arabs have attempted to throw away while carefully trying to destroy any evidence that might be found connecting the Temple Mount to the Jews.

[Jerusalem's Temple Mount Flap](http://archive.archaeology.org/0003/newsbriefs/flap.html)

> A group of archaeology students examined Temple Mount fill dumped by
>   the Waqf in the nearby Kidron Valley and recovered ceramic material and
>   architectural fragments dating to this period and later.

Comment: Thank you so much, may the Moshiach come quickly in our time.